# changing the path in the batch script dynamically on run time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a batch script file to copy and trigger a .exe file installation

So i have coded it as follows:

```
set path = "c:\path_to_install_exe\"

set installationfilepath=%cd%
```

(this one gives, d:\installation_file_path\commands)

the installation file is present in the above path and i want to copy from my current working directory

so i gave the it as

```
echo xcopy "%installationfilepath%\..\install.exe" "%path_to_install_exe%"
```

But this does not do the necessary operation. i get `d:\installation_file_path\commands..\install.exe` as an output.

Can anyone please help me on this, as i am new to batch file scripting.

Comment: **1**) It is not a good idea to change the `path` variable if it not needed, and in this case you don't need it, you are using `%path_to_install_exe%` and `%installationfilepath%` variables. **2**) Try to remove the `echo` that prefixes the `xcopy` command.

Comment: Do not use spaces when using the SET command.  The space is part of the variable **path**.  As MC ND already pointed out.  Do not use the variable %path% as it temporarily destroys the system path variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use pushd and popd to change the directory the batch file assumes.

Like how

```
pushd C:\Users\Arescet\Desktop\ 
echo Hello world! > Hi.txt
popd
```

Will create "Hi.txt" with 'Hello world!' no matter where you launch the bat.

For shorter commands, you're better off setting a different fileName, in the list of  [default variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) 'path' is already a system variable, and it is unwise to change it, as 'MC ND' stated.

For just one single file, you're better off with the [copy command](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) as it lets you indicate the path type.